# ASP.NET Core RC2 Does not show up in VS Community 2015 with updates 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

[image: VS Community 2015 with Update 2] I have installed today (May 18) but when I [follow these instructions](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#create-a-new-project) I do not see:

- ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project template
  All I see is following ASP.NET-5:Asp.NET-5 and asp.net-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-net-core-rc2/) post you will need to install - [.NET Core SDK 1.0 Preview 1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows)

Comment: Thanks. After following your answer I was able to create a .NET Core CR2 web project as it now appears as shown in this image: http://imgur.com/zdEtjOg